# Does webwork in Javascript PostMessage Like SetTimeOut operation that do not have to mutex?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I use webwork to decode h264. when h264.webwork post a frame back to main.js, I put the frame into a [queue](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/queues/) .

I want to know whether I have to use mutex lock?
I think when webwork post message back like settimetout(The main thread is single-threaded) . Am I right?

Comment: javascript and multithreading ... two tags seldom used together

Comment: I think so, But I think more and more js module use webwork. In the future, javascript have more features;

Answer (score 0):

There is no concurrency when an exchange between threads happens.

There 3 cases generally:

1. Objects get serialized/deserialized. (postMessage)
2. Objects change the owner thread, so the old one can no longer access objects.
3. Atomics class from future of JS.

So you do not need to care for consistency. You will simply get a fail if you do something wrong.